# Robocopy; How to copying missing files to a different location from original copy?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, robocopy

I am using Robocopy to transfer around 1 tb worth of files from an external drive to a virtual Windows Server 2008 machine hosted on an ESXi 5.1 VMWare server using USB pass-through.

I used the following (generic) command to transfer the files: Robocopy [external drive path] [Folder path] /mir. This is the output:

**Dirs** :    Total: 1206766       Copied: 990552        Skipped: 216214 
 **Files** :    Total: 11784918      Copied: 9827653       Skipped: 1957256 
 **Bytes** :    Total: 1008.081 g     Copied: 856.294 g     Skipped: 151.786 g 
 **Times** :   69:08:41     56:53:42

**Speed** :                  4488960 Bytes/sec. 
 **Speed** :                  256.860 Megabytes/min.

As you can see, some files were skipped. I think it was because during the process, Robocopy stopped copying 3 times, so i just pressed Enter and the copy continued.

Now, what I want to do is copy the 151.786 gb worth of missing files to a separate location than the original copied files path, because the files that did successfully copy over can not be tampered with right now because they are already being processed into a database. They will be on the same drive of the current copied files, just on a different directory.

Is this possible to accomplish? I think you can't because Robocopy needs the copied batch of files to be able to compare them to the source drive and see which files are missing correct? I know there would probably be a script to accomplish this, but I am a total noob to writing scripts.

Comment: When /MIR is invoked, Robocopy will skip files that are already in the destination and are unchanged. Why do you think they were skipped for some other reason? Do you know for sure they are missing? Your main question really relies on knowing whether the database requires the files to be locked.

Comment: Oh no, these are the results of a first time copy, so all the files should have been copied over. I only added the processing for a database part to emphasize why i can't mess with the files that did copy over. And I don't know if they're missing with absolute certainty because I can;t count the first copied batch of files because they're being uploaded to the database. I just need to be able to copy only the missing files to a separate directory that the original path.